# ASPX WebForms Extension methods in SharePoint

Tags: data-binding, mvvm, sharepoint-2010, webforms

Using [MVVM 4 ASP](http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/09/23/sharepoint-2010-dynamic-compilation-of-aspx-and-ascx-files-with-net-3-5/) in a SharePoint Visual WebPart I am coming across a problem where the compiler is showing me the error:

`'object' does not contain a definition for 'Bind'`

I have put the DLL's containing the methods into the GAC (done by the SP package), referenced the assemblies in the markup, and imported the namespace as follows:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="ASPBinding, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b36aef9f99d7a844" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Binding, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b36aef9f99d7a844" %> 

<%@ Import Namespace="Binding" %>
```

And IntelliSense shows that the page markup is seeing the extension methods:
[image: ASPX Markup view]

Is there a reason why the page compiler sees something different? This works when it is in a normal ASPX page outside of SharePoint.

---

**Update:** OK - seems like a 'problem' with SharePoint.

Out of the box, SP2010 does not use .Net 3.5 to compile ASPX pages - it uses the .Net 2.0 compiler. Who would have thought?!..

Changing the web.config to use the 3.5 compiler allows us to call the extension method ok.

[This is a good post on how to get it working](http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/09/23/sharepoint-2010-dynamic-compilation-of-aspx-and-ascx-files-with-net-3-5/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - seems like a 'problem' with SharePoint.

Out of the box, SP2010 does not use .Net 3.5 to compile ASPX pages - it uses the .Net 2.0 compiler. Who would have thought?!..

[This is a good post on how to get it working](http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/09/23/sharepoint-2010-dynamic-compilation-of-aspx-and-ascx-files-with-net-3-5/).